# Cannot detec dbgshim path for execute path Rider Dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, rider

With the latests update for Rider and Dotnet Core 2.1 There is a bug where you cannot debug your solution.

The error shows something in the lines of:
"Cannot detec dbgshim path for execute path"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a issues allready created at their own issue tracker, which can be found here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-13900

What worked for me was to Clean solution and rebuild my entire project. If it doesn't help go to the link and see the comments for some of the other quick fixes.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who has problem with this issue, I met this problem on somewhere else with Rider.

**Microsoft.Packaging.Tools.Trimming** package also causes this issue. 
Make sure to make **false** TrimUnusedDependencies property on your .csproj file when debug mode enabled.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TrimUnusedDependencies>false</TrimUnusedDependencies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

Clean solution and rebuild didn't work for me, but this did:

1. Build -> Clean solution
2. Files -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest dotnet core SDK (https://www.microsoft.com/net/download) was the solution for me twice.

Answer (score 0):

For me simply removing the `RuntimeIdentifier` property at the top of all the csproj files solved it. Tried all the solutions I could find on the internet and this was the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the solutions here worked for me, I found a solution that worked for me:

When I discovered all the installed .NET Core SDKs on my Windows Machine (via Add / Remove Progams), I found out that .NET Core 3.1 (which is the version that did not work with the debugger anymore) was installed multiple times (probably by visual studio etc.)

So what I did to get debugging working again:

1. Uninstalled Visual Studio
2. Uninstalled all .NET Core 3.X.X Versions of Runtime and/or SDK
3. Reinstalled a fresh .NET Core 3.X.X

I also reinstalled Rider several times before, but I guess that is not really neccessary.

I hope this helps people facing the same problem!